# Trying to change value that gets printed

Tags: json, typescript, database

Im trying to make a custom total from this code.

```
export class EnergySummaryHandler implements Handler {
async Handle(
node: ReportNode,
frequency: ReportFrequency,
from: DateTime,
to: DateTime,
sites: Site
): Promise<Content | null> {
if (node.nodeType !== 'ENERGYTABLE') return null

const tableJsonData = node.data as {
  alarms: boolean
  valueTypes: {
    total: boolean
    lastPeriod: boolean
    samePeriodLastYear: boolean
    thisYear: boolean
    sameTimeLastYear: boolean
    peak: boolean
  }
}
const calculateCustomTotal = (): boolean => {
  // Perform your custom calculation here
  const total = 10; // Replace with your custom calculation logic
  
  // Example custom calculation: Double the total value
  const customTotalValue = total * 2;

  return customTotalValue > 0; // Return a boolean based on your calculation
}

tableJsonData.valueTypes.total = calculateCustomTotal();


const energySummaryTable = new EnergySummaryTable(
  node.sensors,
  frequency,
  from,
  to,
  tableJsonData,
  sites.location.timeZoneName
)
const tableData: EnergySummaryTableData[] =
  await energySummaryTable.getData()
const frekvens = {
  day: 'dag',
  week: 'uke',
  month: 'måned',
  year: 'år',
}[frequency]
const tableHeaders: { title: string; show: boolean }[] = [
  { title: 'Måler', show: true },
  { title: 'Total', show: tableJsonData.valueTypes.total },
```

I've tried to make a const named calculateCustomTotal but that does not change anything. I've also triede to rename tableJsonData, but that does not work either.

Do i need to change the total under tableJsonData from boolean to number? Or is there anything that I am missing?